# how to check for a segmentation dump? how do i debugg it

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

A program to insert first last and in the middle (right aftre element) delete first ,last, selected item and alternate items.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *add;
};
typedef struct node *NODE;
NODE insert_first(NODE start,int item)
{
    NODE temp;
    temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=item;
    temp->add=NULL;
    if(start=NULL)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->add=start;
        start=temp;
    }
    return start;
}
NODE insert_last(NODE start,int item)
{
    NODE temp;
    temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=item;
    temp->add=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        start->add=temp;
    }
}
NODE insert_middle(NODE start,int item)
{
    NODE temp;NODE cur;int flag=0;
    temp=(NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=item;
    temp->add=NULL;
    if(start=NULL)
    {
        return temp;    
    }
    else
    {
        cur=start;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            if(cur->data==item)
            {
                temp->add=cur->add;
                cur->add=temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
NODE delete_first(NODE start)
{
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("The link list is emtpy");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("dleted node is %d",start->data);
        start=start->add;
        free(start);
    }
    return start;
}
NODE delete_last(NODE start)
{
    NODE prev,cur;
    if(start=NULL)
    {
        printf("The list is empty");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cur=start;
        while(cur->add!=NULL)
        {
            prev=cur;
            cur=cur->add;
        }
        prev->add=NULL;
        free(cur);
    }
    return start;
}
NODE delete_middle(NODE start,int item)
{
    NODE prev=NULL,cur;
    if(start=NULL)
    {
        printf("list empty");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        cur=start;
        while(cur->add!=NULL)
        {
            if(cur->data==item)
            {
                prev->add=cur->add;
                free(cur);
                break;
                
            }   
            prev=cur;
            cur=cur->add;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
NODE delete_alt(NODE start)
{
    NODE prev,cur;
    if(start=NULL)
    {
        printf("Emtyp link list");
        return(NULL);
        
    }
    else
    {
        prev=start,cur=start->add;
        while(cur!=NULL && prev!=NULL)
        {
            prev->add=cur->add;
            free(cur);
            if(prev!=NULL)
            {
                cur=prev->add;
            }
        }
    }
}
void dislay(NODE start)
{
    NODE cur;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("Emtpy");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cur=start;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%d->",cur->data);
            cur=cur->add;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    NODE start;int c,item;
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("ENTER 1 for insert first\n");
        printf("ENTER 2 for insert last\n");
        printf("ENTER 3 for insert after element\n");
        printf("ENTER 4 delete first\n");
        printf("ENTER 5 for delete last\n");
        printf("ENTER 6 for dleete middle\n");
        printf("ENTER 7 for delete alternate\n");
        printf("ENTER 8 display");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:printf("Enter the item");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                insert_first(start,item);
                break;
            case 2:printf("Enter the item");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                insert_last(start,item);
                break;
            case 3:printf("Enter the item");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                insert_middle(start,item);
                break;
            case 4: delete_first(start);
                break;
            case 5: delete_last(start);
                break;
            case 6:printf("Enter the item");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                delete_middle(start,item);
                break;
            case 7:delete_alt(start);
                break;
            case 8:dislay(start);
                break;
            default:exit(0);
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i finished writting this code ...has not syntax errors. But it has segmentation faults. What is the mistake and what should i do to avoid this segmentation faults and how do i find these faults???..
this is not the first time i have a problem

Comment: Run it under valgrind.

Comment: `if(start=NULL)` ==> `if (!start)`. Or `if (start == NULL`. Check the return value of `malloc()` and don't be so parsimonious with whitespace and linefeeds. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @Tom Indeed, I did.

Comment: @TomKarzes it was suppose to be if(start==NULL)...but stilll the same problem

Comment: OT: don't typedef pointer types, it only causes confusion.

Comment: You don't initialize `start`. `start` is a pointer (which is not really obvious at first sight, because of the typedef). Therefore `start` points nowhere, hence the segfault. And there is a typo in `if (start = NULL)`, it should be `==`. And `insert_first` returns a pointer, but you don't use the result in the calling code. And probably some more errors.

Comment: Run the code in a debugger. It will stop at the fault and you can examine your variables.

Comment: @Haris I deleted my comment, you can delete your's and I'll delete this one as well.

Comment: It's an interactive program.  Please edit your question and tell us how you  reproduce the segfault (or even better hard-code a failing test case in `main()`).

Answer (score 0):

1. `if(start=NULL)` assigns NULL to start and is always false.
2. (Partially fixed) Check the return value from `scanf()` otherwise you are operating on unitialized values.  You may need to flush the stdin by reading till you get a EOF or `\n`.
3. Don't cast the `void *` from `malloc()`.
4. Refactoring all the duplicate code.  The 3 insert functions all do the same thing just at a different place in the linked list.
5. `insert_middle()` is simply wrong.  Two different names is confusing but apparently the idea is to insert a new node with `item` after a node with a given value `search`.  Two values are not read in `main()` and two values are not passed to `insert_middle()`.
6. `insert_last()` doesn't loop so it can't possibly find the last node when you don't maintain a pointer to it.
7. `delete_first()` is simply wrong.  You advance to the 2nd node which you free then return a pointer to memory that was just free'ed:

```
        start=start->add;
        free(start);
    }
    return start;
```

7. `delete_last()`: may operate on `prev` before it's initialized.
8. `main()`; `start` is not initialized.
9. `main()`: All the functions that may change `start` like `insert_first(start,item);` needs to assign the return value to `start` (or pass in &start which is pointer to pointer so you can update it).
10. `main()`: The way prompts are missing space/newlines makes it hard to read; also the error that the list is empty is written 3 different ways.
11. `main()`: not sure what delete alt is supposed to do so I removed it along with the implementation.
12. `main()`: moved menu outside loop just to make the output easier to read.
13. `main()`: use `goto out;` instead of `exit(0)` to free the memory that has been allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EMPTY "Empty\n"
#define NOT_FOUND "The node %d was not found\n"
#define DELETE "Deleted node is %d\n"

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *add;
} *NODE;

NODE create_node(int data, NODE add) {
    NODE n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    n->data = data;
    n->add = add;
    return n;
}

NODE insert_first(NODE start, int item) {
    return create_node(item, start);
}

NODE insert_last(NODE start, int item) {
    if(!start)
        return create_node(item, start);
    NODE cur = start;
    for(; cur->add; cur=cur->add);
    cur->add = create_node(item, NULL);
    return start;
}

NODE insert_after(NODE start, int after, int item) {
    NODE cur=start;
    for(; cur && cur->data != after; cur=cur->add);
    if(!cur) {
        printf(NOT_FOUND, after);
        return start;
    }
    cur->add = create_node(item, cur->add);
    return start;
}

NODE delete_first(NODE start) {
    if(!start) {
        printf("%s", EMPTY);
        return NULL;
    }
    printf(DELETE, start->data);
    NODE tmp = start->add;
    free(start);
    return tmp;
}

NODE delete_item(NODE start,int item) {
    if(!start || !start->add && start->data != item) {
        printf(NOT_FOUND, item);
        return start;
    }
    if(start->data == item)
        return delete_first(start);

    NODE cur = start;
    for(; cur && cur->add && cur->add->data != item; cur=cur->add);
    if(!cur || !cur->add || cur->add->data != item) {
        printf(NOT_FOUND, item);
        return start;
    }
    NODE tmp = cur->add->add;
    free(cur->add);
    cur->add = tmp;
    return start;
}

NODE delete_last(NODE start) {
    if(!start) {
        printf("%s", EMPTY);
        return NULL;
    }
    if(!start->add) {
        printf(DELETE, start->data);
        free(start);
        return NULL;
    }
    NODE cur = start;
    for(; cur->add->add; cur=cur->add);
    printf(DELETE, cur->add->data);
    free(cur->add);
    cur->add = NULL;
    return start;
}

void dislay(NODE start) {
    if(!start) {
        printf("Emtpy\n");
        return;
    }
    for(NODE cur=start; cur; cur=cur->add)
        printf("%d%s",cur->data, cur->add ? "->" : "\n");
}

int main() {
    printf("ENTER 1 for insert first\n");
    printf("ENTER 2 for insert last\n");
    printf("ENTER 3 for insert after element\n");
    printf("ENTER 4 delete first\n");
    printf("ENTER 5 for delete last\n");
    printf("ENTER 6 for delete item\n");
    printf("ENTER 8 display\n");

    NODE start = NULL;
    for(;;) {
        printf("What would you like to do? ");
        int c;
        if(scanf("%d",&c) != 1) {
            printf("scanf failed\n");
            goto out;
        }
        switch(c) {
            case 1: {
                printf("Enter the item: ");
                int item;
                if(scanf("%d",&item) != 1) {
                    printf("scanf failed\n");
                    goto out;
                }
                start = insert_first(start,item);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                printf("Enter the item: ");
                int item;
                scanf("%d",&item);
                start = insert_last(start,item);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                printf("Enter the new item after: ");
                int after;
                scanf("%d", &after);
                printf("Enter the item: ");
                int item;
                scanf("%d", &item);
                start = insert_after(start, after, item);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
                start = delete_first(start);
                break;
            case 5:
                start = delete_last(start);
                break;
            case 6: {
                printf("Enter the item: ");
                int item;
                scanf("%d", &item);
                start = delete_item(start,item);
                break;
            }
            case 8:
                dislay(start);
                break;
            default:
                goto out;
        }
    }
out:
    while(start = delete_first(start));
    return 0;
}
```

and example session:

```
ENTER 1 for insert first
ENTER 2 for insert last
ENTER 3 for insert after element
ENTER 4 delete first
ENTER 5 for delete last
ENTER 6 for delete item
ENTER 8 display
What would you like to do? 1
Enter the item: 1
What would you like to do? 2
Enter the item: 3
What would you like to do? 3
Enter the new item after: 1
Enter the item: 2
What would you like to do? 8
1->2->3
What would you like to do? 4
Deleted node 1
What would you like to do? 5
Deleted node 3
What would you like to do? 6
Enter the item: 2
Deleted node 2
What would you like to do? 8
Emtpy
```